.Net Common exception handling
I have multiple .Net controllers that look like:
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Int32>> GetById(Int32 id)
{
    id = FormatId(id);
    return lookupId(id);
}

Assume I have dozens of these endpoints in multiple controllers and some of them require the id to be formatted a certain way like an integer padded to 5 digits, so the FormatId pads it for me and if it's more than 5 digits, it throws a BadHttpRequestException.
Now instead of littering all of the id related endpoints with:
try/catch { return BadRequest() }

Is there anyway I can attach a common exception handler to any/all endpoints/controllers?
Basically I just want to do something like:
Controller.OnException(Exception e)
{
    if (e.Type == BadHttpRequestException) // Ignore invalid C# syntax, just pseudocode
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}

I assume that would be the supported way, or can I have access to the layer above the controller's endpoint such that I could catch it myself and do something like:
public MyWrapperEndpoint(T endpoint)
{
    try {
        endpoint(); // call whatever endpoint was requested (GetById)
    } catch (BadHttpRequestException e) {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);  // Return the common exception message
    }
}

Essentially my question boils down to, if my lower layers are throwing BadHttpRequestException (or any other exception I know I am explicitly throwing), how can I easily force all of my controller endpoints to catch that exception and return a BadRequest object?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#exception-filters

Instead of a 400 Bad Request, I would put a custom route constraint on the id placeholder and let it return 404 Not Found, since it would/should never find something that doesn't match the format.

It is called Global Exception handling by Implementing Middleware in .Net
Using Middleware to trap Exceptions in Asp.Net Core
ASP.NET Core Web API exception handling

I think a middleware catching the unhandling exepctions should be able to fit your needs:
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (BadHttpRequestException ex)
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new
            {
                message = ex.Message,
            });
        }
    }
}

And then you added it as a middleware on your startup or program depending on where you build your app:
builder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

The middleware lets the controller call the service logic, the service logic will throw the exception, and if you don't catch the exception on your controller layer, the middleware will catch it. The good thing about this approach, is that you still can catch exceptions in you controllers and return different status codes or behaviors. The middleware is the lifeguard of all endpoint controllers without try/catch.
Notice I only put your BadHttpRequestException, but you could follow along catching all types and the generic one Exception.
